# Blocking JavaScript code execution on page until image onerror event

Tags: javascript, bitrix

I have a very interesting task:

I have few "images" like that:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src='https://www.hootv.lt/bitrix/spread.php?s=QklUUklYX1NNX1VJREgBbjVkZXNEQ2IzVnU4ckRSSmlCbW82R0xKdmNWcUV2UzUBMAEvAQExATECQklUUklYX1NNX1VJREwBMzcwNjU0NTQyMDcBMAEvAQExATECQklUUklYX1NNX1VJREQBMjVwbmJzNjNkY2VrNGRuZ2VmaGEyYXZsMm1taGh6YWMBMTcyNjMzNjUzMAEvAQExATECQklUUklYX1NNX05DQwFZATE3MjYzMzY1MzABLwEBAQJCSVRSSVhfU01fQ0MBATABLwEBAQI%3D&k=c545bd21253d81d854fc3698d4b20854';
```

An image src is a PHP page which returns nothing. I have to check whenever all images generate error, than continue executing script.

So my script should look like something like that:

```
<script> - My code
var image = new Image();
image.src='url1';

var image = new Image();
image.src='url2';

var image = new Image();
image.src='url3';

...

var image = new Image();
image.src='url33';
</script>

(after all images generate onerror event continue with)

<script> - CMS generated code I cannot change
windows.location.href = "..."; (i cannot change line, all I can do is inject the script above)
</script>
```

I tried the following but obviously it's not working:

```
while (!image.error) {
  //wait
}
```

Comment: You cannot "block JavaScript code execution". You could conceivably use a Promise mechanism to go one by one through the image URLs, but that's not really "blocking".

Comment: @Pointy can u give me an example paying an attention that I cannot change line windows.location.href = "...";? Thanks!

Comment: Well if you cannot change it *at all*, including moving it into a  context that is predicated on a series of image loads succeeding, then you're out of luck.

Comment: @Pointy I can't do it and that's the main problem. I updated my code so it would be easier to understand why it is like so...

Comment: You have to use `Promises`, especially the `Promise.all()` function should do its job.

Comment: @AztecCodes can u provide me with an example?

Comment: Maybe a better approach is to get rid of bad URLs from the image list in the first place, because given the edits to your question you absolutely cannot prevent that inserted `<script>` tag from running.

Comment: @ViacheslavRavdin I posted an answer. Check it out.

Comment: @Pointy I understand what're u talking about but bad URLs aren't bad, they do their job, anyway, it's a hack from CMS authors and I cannot do anything about it.

Comment: @ViacheslavRavdin Then you should ask the CMS authors to fix their hack, as it doesn't work. It's not clear what problem they were trying to solve or why they chose images to do that, but this is not a proper solution.

Comment: @Bergi I will definitely write them a letter so they will apply my fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would like to say big thanks to @CherryDT and @AztecCodes for being so involved in my problem!

It seems like the problem I faced doesn't have a straightforward solution so I ended up modifying CMS source code for my needs.

```
        var srcs = [
        ...
        ];
        var promises = [];
        $.each(srcs, function(key, src) {
            promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = src;
                image.onerror = function() {
                    resolve();
                }
            }));
        });
        $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
            //redirect here
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky problem. I have a solution but it is a hack (of course), because this is not something that normally needs to be done. I don't even know whether this will work on all browsers, and for how long it will work (but I tested on Chrome 116 and Firefox 117 and it was OK in those).

First a big warning:

## This is not recommended. It's a big hack. Use at your own risk.

But I understand that desparate times call for desparate measures. I hope this is a temporary solution and you'll spend some time later to figure out how to solve the issue in your CMS (perhaps you can write a plugin which hooks the part of the CMS that inserts this code and stops it from doing so).

---

You can't stop the code below from running, at least I couldn't come up with any way to do that (even a `MutationObserver` will fire *after* the code ran, I checked). So we can try to do the next best thing, which is stopping the redirection from executing.

I tried redefining `window.location` and `window.location.href` but that's not possible because those properties are defined with `configurable: false` by default. We also can't play tricks on the `Window` or `Location` prototypes. But what we can do is overwrite the redirection with our own redirection, but this time to a page that returns a [status code 204](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204) which will essentially cancel the navigation!

This is what I came up with, after some playing around and testing ideas:

```js
window.addEventListener(
  'beforeunload',
  () => setTimeout(() => location.href = 'https://www.google.com/gen_204', 1),
  { once: true }
)
```

This will cancel the next navigation attempt. You can later navigate yourself. If the URL that the page redirects to is not fixed and you need to know what it was so you can redirect to it later, you can save it within the event handler, and access that variable later (e.g. after all your images failed to load):

```js
let redirectTarget

window.addEventListener(
  'beforeunload',
  () => {
    redirectTarget = location.href
    setTimeout(() => location.href = 'https://www.google.com/gen_204', 1)
  },
  { once: true }
)
```

A few things to note here:

- This relies on the URL `https://www.google.com/gen_204` to return status 204. It's probably better if you add your endpoint that returns status 204 and use that instead.
- This will cancel the next navigation attempt that happens, regardless of what caused it. This means that in case that script tag is *not* on the page for some reason, it would instead cancel the next link click or even the user's own navigation attempts from typing a new URL in the address bar! So if there is any possibility of the redirection *not* existing on the page below, you should probably add a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler that removes the `beforeunload` event handler.
- This might stop working anytime. The fact that this can even interfere with the user's own navigation actions sounds to me as if it could be abused as well, so it's possible that browser vendors will make this trick intentionally stop working at some point.
- Yes, the `setTimeout` *is* required. Attempting to change `location` from within the invokation of the `beforeunload` handler is silently ignored by the browser.

Note: I didn't explain how to actually wait for the images to fail loading, only how to stop the navigation (the trickier part). For how to do the waiting, check out [AztecCodes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77145065/1871033).